# How do I sum data based on a PART of the headers name?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Say I have columns

### /670 - White | /650 - black | /680 - Red |  /800 - Whitest

These have data in their rows. Basically, I want to SUM their values together if their headers contain my desired string.
For modularity's sake, I wanted to merely specify to sum /670, /650, and /680 without having to mention the rest of the header text.

So, something like =SUMIF(a1:c1; "/NUM & /NUM & /NUM"; a2:c2)

That doesn't work, and honestly I don't know what i should be looking for.

Additional stuff:

- I'm trying to think of the answer myself, is it possible to mention the header text as condition for ifs? Like: if A2="/650 - Black" then proceed to sum the next header. Is this possible?
- Possibility it would not involve VBA, a draggable formula would be preferable!
- At this point, I may as well request a version which handles the complete header name rather than just a part of it as I believe it to be difficult for formula code alone.

Thanks for having a look!

Let me know if I need to elaborate.

EDIT: In regards to data samples, any positive number will do actually, damn shame stack overflow doesn't support table markdown. Anyway, for example then..:

```
    +-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
    |      A      |      B      |      C      |      D      |      E      |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 |/650 - Black |/670 - White |/800 - White |/680 - Red   |/650 - Black |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2 |     250     |     400     |     100     |     300     |     125     |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I should have clarified:

The number range for these headers would go from /100 - /9999 and no more than that.

EDIT:

Progress so far:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GiJKFcPWzG5bDsNt93eG7WS_M5uuVk9cvkt2VGSbpxY/edit?usp=sharing

Formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:D2*
(MID($A$1:$D$1,2,4)=IF(LEN($H$1)=4,$H$1&"",$H$1&" ")))+(A2:D2*
(MID($A$1:$D$1,2,4)=IF(LEN($I$1)=4,$I$1&"",$I$1&" ")))+(A2:D2*
(MID($A$1:$D$1,2,4)=IF(LEN($J$1)=4,$J$1&"",$J$1&" "))))
```

Apparently, each MID function is returning false with each F9 calculation.

EDIT EDIT:

Okay! I found my issue, it's the /being read when you ALSO mentioned that it wasn't required. Man, I should stop skimming!

Final Edit:

```
    =SUMPRODUCT((RETURNSUM*
(MID(HEADER,2,4)=IF(LEN(Match5)=4,Match5&"",Match5&" ")))+(RETURNSUM*
(MID(HEADER,2,4)=IF(LEN(Match6)=4,Match6&"",Match6&" ")))+(RETURNSUM*
(MID(HEADER,2,4)=IF(LEN(Match7)=4,Match7&"",Match7&" ")))
```

The idea is that Header and RETURNSUM will become match criteria like the matches written above, that way it would be easier to punch new criterion into the search table. As of the moment, it doesn't support multiple rows/dragging.

Comment: add some data examples

Comment: I would suggest something like `=SUM(IF(LEFT(A2,4)="/650",SUM(A3:A100)),IF(LEFT(B2,4)="/650",SUM(B3:B100)))` this will get you started. from there you could perhaps expand into researching `SUMPRODUCT` or array formulas to do it much cleaner but there's a lot to learn there before you get comfortable using them. (I would provide a working example and breakdown but I due for a meeting in 10 minutes and wouldn't get it done in time)

Comment: I'll mess around with your code snippet when I get back to work. @Glitch_Doctor.

Comment: Let's say that you were looking for "/650", "/670" & "/680". This in my edit (if it gets approved) represents columns A, B, D and E. (I have assumed that the prefix `/***` could appear more than once as a header). My understanding is that you want the entire column to be summed (or are you just after a single row to be summed?) only where this prefix is found, is this correct? I would assume that you will want this to change based on user input, would you always be searching for 3 prefixes or does this vary from time to time, how will you want to input the data etc. please elaborate, thanks.

Comment: please elaborate on _"Any cell = "Solution" Sum(A2:E2)"_: what is a possible input and corresponding expected output?

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor, the idea I had was that I would put the solution formula after, say ,125 from your edit and then drag it down in the case of multiple rows of data. So probably not a sum all data solution, but a row by row one. So the solution for example would be on F2, mentioning /650, /680, /670, and the face value would be simply 1075. (Oh, wait i think the edit contains two 650's.) At any rate, the only thing that causes me concern is the 'header name as condition' requirement, each header name will be unique '/650','/651' so one name isn't shared. /9999 is the limit for header numbers.

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor, the first solution was great, and it answered a question I didn't know needed asking! (Left function) I couldn't get the second if to work though, without it the first Sum(if) works. At any rate, the main question intended on summing horizontally, like with an if check per line rather than a vertical range.

Comment: I can knock something up and talk you through it, especially as all prefixes are unique. What would the maximum number of searches be? Would these be different for each row or constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have knocked up a couple of formulas that will achieve what you are looking for. For ease I have made the search input require the number only as pressing <kbd>/</kbd> does not automatically type into the formula bar. I apologise for the length of the answer, I got a little carried away with the explanation.

I have set this up for 3 criteria located in `J1`, `K1` and `L1`.

**Here is the output I achieved:**
[image]

**Formula 1 - SUMPRODUCT():**
`=SUMPRODUCT((A4:G4*(MID($A$1:$G$1,2,4)=IF(LEN($J$1)=4,$J$1&"",$J$1&" ")))+(A4:G4*(MID($A$1:$G$1,2,4)=IF(LEN($K$1)=4,$K$1&"",$K$1&" ")))+(A4:G4*(MID($A$1:$G$1,2,4)=IF(LEN($L$1)=4,$L$1&"",$L$1&" "))))`

`Sumproduct(array1,[array2])` behaves as an array formula without needed to be entered as one. Array formulas break down ranges and calculate them cell by cell (in this example we are using single rows so the formula will assess columns seperately).

`(A4:G4*(MID($A$1:$G$1,2,4)=IF(LEN($J$1)=4,$J$1&"",$J$1&" ")))`

Essentially I have broken the `Sumproduct()` formula into 3 identical parts - 1 for each search condition. `(A4:G4*`: Now, as the formula behaves like an array, we will multiply each individual cell by either 1 or 0 and add the results together.

1 is produced when the next part of the formula is true and 0 for when it is false (default numeric values for `TRUE`/`FALSE`).

`(MID($A$1:$G$1,2,4)=IF(LEN($J$1)=4,$J$1&"",$J$1&" "))`

`MID(text,start_num,num_chars)` is being used here to assess the 4 digits after the `"/"` and see whether they match with the number in the 3 cells that we are searching from (in this case the first one: `J1`). Again, as `SUMPRODUCT()` works very much like an array formula, each cell in the range will be assessed individually.

I have then used the `IF(logical_test,[value_if_true],[value_if_false])` to check the length of the number that I am searching. As we are searching for a 4 digit text string, if the number is 4 digits then add nothing (`""`) to force it to a text string and if it is not (as it will have to be 3 digits) add 1 space to the end (`" "`) again forcing it to become a text string.

The formula will then perform the calculation like so:
The `MID()` formula produces the array: `{"650 ","670 ","800 ","680 ","977 ","9999","143 "}`. This combined with the first search produces `{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}` which when multiplied by `A4:G4`
(remember 0 for false and 1 for true) produces this array: `{250,0,0,0,0,0,0}` essentially pulling the desired result ready to be summed together.

**Formula 2: =SUM(IF(Array)): *[This formula does not work for 3 digit numbers as they will exist within the 4 digit numbers! I have included it for educational purposes only]*** 
`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($J$1,$A$1:$G$1)),A8:G8),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($K$1,$A$1:$G$1)),A8:G8),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($L$1,$A$1:$G$1)),A8:G8))`

The formula will need to be entered as an array (once copy and pasted while still in the formula bar hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>)

This formula works in a similar way, `SUM()` will add together the array values produced where `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH()` columns match the result column.

`SEARCH()` will return a number when it finds the exact characters in a cell which represents it's position in number of characters. By using `ISNUMBER()` I am avoiding having to do the whole `MID()` and `IF(LEN()=4,""," ")` I used in the previous formula as `TRUE`/`FALSE` will be produced when a match is found regardless of it's position or cell formatting.

As previously mentioned, this poses a problem as `999` can be found within `9999` etc.

The resulting array for the first part is: `{250,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}` (if you would like to see the array you can highlight that part of the formula and calculate with <kbd>F9</kbd> but be sure to highlight the exact brackets for that part of the formula).

*I hope I have explained this well, feel free to ask any questions about stuff that you don't understand. It is good to see people keen to learn and not just fishing for a fast answer. I would be more than happy to help and explain in more depth.*

Comment: Aha! I missed that you already mentioned it. I was terribly confused that you were attempting to multiply a string range with a number, then it dawned on me that it returned 1, so the value that was searched transposed over! It's amazing, the wall is starting to make sense now.

Comment: If you don't mind going over my adaptation of your code, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GiJKFcPWzG5bDsNt93eG7WS_M5uuVk9cvkt2VGSbpxY/edit?usp=sharing   I don't know why I'm coming up with a zero here despite everything looking sound. P.S: GoogleSheets seems to have altered my formula abit to I'll update the OP with my progress. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm perfectly happy with the code you've produced, but now I'm doing some experimenting. I created a version of my table with a truly random placement of header names, so I pictured that instead of writing a range with a small scope, I would write a range with the ENTIRE scope of headers. This doesn't work, and I'm wondering why it's returning a #Value. I'm testing with a scope of A1:FY1 for the headers. And an A2:FY2 for the return sum. The return sum returns the #Num! error on the other hand. Is there a way to make this idea feasible?

Comment: Hmm, I'll try and take a look when I'm at home as the business systems here can't access google sheets. I might not be able to achieve this, but would probably give index match a go for it. What I would need to know is: a) would the /1234 defining prefix appear only once in each column & b) how will we establish what value to sum together from each column?   [please post another question as this is technically a new request, feel free to link to this one as reference]

Comment: I did a little testing on a brand new spreadsheet with the same amount of data, and now it works fine... weird, it's literally copy pasted. Though I have another question! If I were to make the header range and the return sum range a named cell in the same fashion as the match criteria. How would I make it draggable as well, the way it is now? I'll update the op with the formula.

Comment: Made a new thread for the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743488/how-do-i-make-this-formula-support-multiple-rows-dragging

Answer (score 1):

I start this solution with the names in an array, you can read the header names into an array with not too much difficulty.

```
Sub test()
    Dim myArray(1 To 4) As String
    myArray(1) = "/670 - White"
    myArray(2) = "/650 - black"
    myArray(3) = "/680 - Red"
    myArray(4) = "/800 - Whitest"

    For Each ArrayValue In myArray
    'Find position of last character
        endposition = InStr(1, ArrayValue, " - ", vbTextCompare)
    'Grab the number section from the string, based on starting and ending positions
        stringvalue = Mid(ArrayValue, 2, endposition - 2)
    'Convert to number
        NumberValue = CLng(stringvalue)
    'Add to total
        Total = Total + NumberValue
    Next ArrayValue
    'Print total
    Debug.Print Total
End Sub
```

This will print the answer to the debug window.