# Is it possible to perform this SumIf without knowing the target range?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

This is my code so far, refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673137/how-do-i-sum-data-based-on-a-part-of-the-headers-name?noredirect=1#comment70553977_41673137) as to what I am trying to do.

```
 =SUM(IF(LEFT(C$2,4)="/111",SUM(C3,G3)))
```

As you can see, I am defining C2, the point of my header, and in the Sum, I am defining the sum range. I now have this question:

- How do I proceed if I do not know where my header is exactly, but I
  know that I'm looking for a 'part' of the header. How do I search for
  this? With an HLookUp? This is because these headers may be placed in just about any order, because of this, I will need to search for the text rather than    define its place.

For example, I have this table:

```
    +-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
    |      A      |      B      |      C      |      D      |      E      |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 |/650 - Black |/670 - White |/800 - White |/680 - Red   |/650 - Black |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2 |     250     |     400     |     100     |     300     |     125     |
+---+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I want to sum up the row of data where I specify the 4 character LEFT limited header, as it is in the code I posted. The problem here is that the code is more of a, "This.Cell, if it is your desired header, add stuff" when I wanted something more like "Where.Cell matches LEFT limited header, add their stuff (horizontal by other matches, not vertical) I think an Index Match is what I'm looking for, but from what I gathered, the data would have to be defined on a cell, which, as per the table above, does not contain it.

I created a separate question as I believe the requirements were not stated properly the first time, resulting in a different direction and a different answer.

Pure formula is preferred, but if VBA is what you've thought up, I'd still like to read it.

TLDR: In excel, I define several left limited headers, left limited because past the / and four digits, the rest of the text may be different. I search the sheet for these headers, and when found, I sum them up and place them at the point of this formula.

I hope I was able to clarify my requirements clearer this time!

EDIT:

So I just wanted to reiterate that the requirements of this formula is that I have no idea *where* my headers are located despite the table I wrote above. The idea is that I will always have a /650, a /670, or a /680. The number arrangement doesn't even matter at this point. I don't know if this is possible at all, because, since I don't know where the headers are, only what they are, I don't know what letter the cell will be on, only that it is the "cell where the header was found".

Say I want /670 and a /680. Formula finds the header /670 first, and gets its cellspace like "/670 is on C1! Therefore the number that has to be added is C2!". Proceed to the next, /680 and do the same thing. In the end, I hit enter on the formula and out comes the sum of these two headers = 700.

I'm thinking in terms of C# code where I could probably state that the range to be added is based on the letter of the header I found, no idea if excel can do this much less as a draggable formula, which is why I posted this question.

Comment: please show a possible minimal and complete input data and corresponding desired output

Comment: You could try to use the SumIf formula: `=SUMIFS(A2:G2,criteria_range,"=/111")`, but it will require from you to create an additional row for criteria with the `=Left() ` values.

Comment: When I reread the question my given answer will not fit. So I deleted it. Please clarify what shall be the result from your given table for header starts with "/670"? Is it: sum the whole one row if any header starts with "/670"?

Comment: @AxelRichter, Oh, no. It's more of the variables that get chucked to the equation. Like, if I would include /670, /650, /680, I am adding the row value of these. What I dont know is how to handle the fact that I don't know WHERE these headers are, so I don't know how to word the cell where the data is located.  I'll update the OP with an example.

Comment: Where you "would include /670, /650, /680"? Please show the desired result in your question.

Comment: Updated the OP, let me know if I clarified your confusion!

Comment: you say _"Say I want /670 and a /680."_: where would you write those wanted headers so that any formula or code could grab and make calculations out of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your sample table and your description this is what `SUMPRODUCT` is for. Sum products of arrays. Here the first array is an array of 0 or 1 where 1 is if the header matches one of the desired headers 0 if not. The second array is the array of values to sum.

So:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT($A$1:$E$1,4)={"/670";"/650";"/680"})*$A$2:$E$2)
```

will result in 1075 = 250 + 400 + 300 + 125.

The desired headers could also be given in a cell range. But this must be a column range (1 column, multiple rows). For example given the folowing

```
    G
1 /650
2 /670
3 /680
```

then:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT($A$1:$E$1,4)=$G$1:$G$3)*$A$2:$E$2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume, what you're looking for is an array formula which is almost the same as the one you already used:

```
{=SUM(IF(LEFT(A1:A3,4)="/670",B1:B3),IF(LEFT(A1:A3,4)="/680",B1:B3))}
```

Hit `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`